# Multiple levels of indent in markdown?

Tags: support, markdown

I know that I can use `Ctrl+k` to change:

void chengXu()
{
string xinXi="niHaoShiJie";
Console.WriteLine(xinXi);
}

into

```
void chengXu()
{
string xinXi="niHaoShiJie";
Console.WriteLine(xinXi);
}
```

Let's say I want to perform a second block indent to make this into:

```
void chengXu()
{
   string xinXi="niHaoShiJie";
   Console.WriteLine(xinXi);
}
```

Is there a command for adding another indent, or subtracting an indent, the same way that `Tab` vs `Shift+Tab` works in Notepad++?

Comment: You can apply this trick here, though: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294681/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-for-formatting-code-under-numbered-lists/294689#294689

Comment: @editors: please do not format first code snippet. It's part of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SE does not support this, so you have to use a userscript, such as [SE like I like it](https://stackapps.com/questions/5038/se-like-i-like-it-userscript), which lets you <kbd>Tab</kbd> to indent or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to outdent.

Answer (score 1):

No.